# Angular: one-time-binding for ngClass with multiple values

Tags: javascript, angularjs, one-time-binding

I would like to use one-time binding for the following situation

```
<div ng-class="{a: someValueA, b: someValueB}">....</div>
```

If I would like to use one-time binding for the whole expression I know you can do

```
<div ng-class="::{a: someValueA, b: someValueB}">....</div>
```

However, in my case I only want to use one-time binding just for one of the two. Lets assume that I only want to use one-time binding for `someValueA`, I've tried the following

```
<div ng-class="{a: ::someValueA, b: someValueB}">....</div>
```

or

```
<div ng-class="[::{a: someValueA}, {b: someValueB}]">....</div>
```

None of them work (errors) Any suggestions how to do this?

Comment: what you are trying to accomplish isn't currently part of the framework.  `ng-class` is the directive that is bound to the object which has multiple properties.  you can only one time bind the entire object.

Comment: How unfortunate.  Thanks!

Comment: I would simply go with class in model: http://plnkr.co/edit/uGIPAec97F9bBUxQHbcm?p=preview